# ServiceStack AsyncPost exception handling not working

Tags: exception, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack (the ServiceStack client is 4.0.12.0).

I have some code as below:

```
    private async Task TestSave()
    {
        JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:60982");
        try
        {
            this.Items = client.Post(new ItemDescUpdateRequest() { Items = this.Items });

        }
        catch (WebServiceException ex)
        {
            HandleWebException(ex);
        }

    }
```

If I use Post and the server throws an exception. The server exception comes back correctly. I can use ex.ErrorMessage to see the message. However, If I change to:

```
            this.Items = await client.PostAsync(new ItemDescUpdateRequest() { Items = this.Items
```

the exception does not get handled correctly.

The ResponseBody has data in it as does the ResponseDTO. However ResponseStatus is null. ErrorCode and ErrorMessage get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException error, I am assuming because ResponseStatus is null.

Why doesn't PostAsync work as expected?

Comment: Can you first try updating libraries on NuGet, and if that doesn't work please add the full Request + Response DTO and stacktrace.

Comment: I think it has something to do with other stuff which is only surfaced when I use PostAsync and forcing some await/async stuff to happen. In the above code this.Items is an ObservableCollection. If I recall data from the server and make no changes then do the above code, the server exception is returned properly for processing. If  I manually add a new object to this.Items then the exception is handled properly. If I add a new object through my grid control to the ObservableCollection, it does NOT work properly. Very weird

Comment: For async, you can potentially try: `client.CaptureSynchronizationContext = true`

Comment: Tried the CaptureSynchronizationContext and also updated to latest servicestack. No good :-(

Comment: Not sure why then, there aren't issues with async Exceptions in tests. Can you post the Response DTO and the raw HTTP Response using Fiddler?

Comment: Strangely I don't see any data coming through Fiddler. That was first place I went to. I am seeing traffic for other websites but not the ServiceStack stuff even though I am using http. For the time being I have simply used Post instead of PostAsync. This particularly usage is only a very small part of the project and unfortunately I need to move on to the main part of the project where ServiceStack is workign wonderfully.